# Why does this SQSQueuePolicy fail to create in AWS CloudFormation?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-sqs

I've created the following CloudFormation template:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: Creates all resources necessary to send SES emails & track bounces/complaints through AWS
Resources:
  IAMUser:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::User'
    Properties:
      UserName: iam-ses-sqs
  SQSQueue:
    Type: 'AWS::SQS::Queue'
    Properties:
      QueueName: ses-queue
  SNSTopic:
    Type: 'AWS::SNS::Topic'
    Properties:
      TopicName: sns-notifications
  IAMUserPolicy:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Policy'
    Properties:
      PolicyName: IAM_Send_SES_Email
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - 'SES:SendEmail'
              - 'SES:SendRawEmail'
            Resource: 'arn:aws:ses:*:*:identity/*'
      Users:
        - !Ref IAMUser
  SQSQueuePolicy:
    Type: 'AWS::SQS::QueuePolicy'
    Properties:
      Queues:
        - !Ref SQSQueue
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Action:
              - 'SQS:ReceiveMessage'
              - 'SQS:DeleteMessage'
              - 'SQS:GetQueueAttributes'
            Effect: Allow
            Resource: !Ref SQSQueue
            Principal:
              AWS:
                - !Ref IAMUser
  SNSTopicSubscription:
    Type: 'AWS::SNS::Subscription'
    Properties:
      Protocol: SQS
      Endpoint: !GetAtt 
        - SQSQueue
        - Arn
      TopicArn: !Ref SNSTopic
```

I'd like to allow IAMUser to perform the SQS ReceiveMessage, DeleteMessage, and GetQueueAttributes actions on the SQSQueue resource. SQSQueue should also be subscribed to the SNSTopic.

When creating a stack using this template in CloudFormation, the SQSQueue, SNSTopic, SNSTopicSubscription, IAMUser, and IAMUserPolicy all create with no problem, in that order. However, the SQSQueuePolicy fails to create and generates the error message:
`Invalid value for the parameter Policy. (Service: AmazonSQS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidAttributeValue; Request ID: {request id})`

Why is this failing, and how should I modify the template to ensure that all resources and their associated policies/subscriptions are created successfully?

Comment: It is rather strange to add an IAM User into an SQS Queue Policy. If you are granting access to a user, it is better to grant that permission on the IAM User themselves, rather than putting it in the Queue Policy. This way, when more users need that permission, or when users leave the organization, there is no need to keep changing the Queue Policy. It might also hit length limits. However, using the Queue Policy is good when granting **cross-account permissions**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found two problems in your CloudFormation template.

The first one, like Marcin said, the resource reference must be the Queue ARN and not the Queue URL.

```
Resource: !GetAtt SQSQueue.Arn
```

The second one is that your AWS reference is with your IAM user but it must be the Account ID.

```
Principal:
  AWS:
    - !Ref 'AWS::AccountId'
```

That said, I was able to create successfully the CloudFormation Stack in my account with this CloudFormation Template:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: Creates all resources necessary to send SES emails & track bounces/complaints through AWS
Resources:
  IAMUser:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::User'
    Properties:
      UserName: iam-ses-sqs
  SQSQueue:
    Type: 'AWS::SQS::Queue'
    Properties:
      QueueName: ses-queue
  SQSQueuePolicy:
    Type: 'AWS::SQS::QueuePolicy'
    Properties:
      Queues:
        - !Ref SQSQueue
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Action:
              - 'SQS:ReceiveMessage'
              - 'SQS:DeleteMessage'
              - 'SQS:GetQueueAttributes'
            Effect: Allow
            Resource: !GetAtt SQSQueue.Arn
            Principal:
              AWS:
                - !Ref 'AWS::AccountId'
```

Comment: Thanks much for the detailed explanation! Rather than changing the Principal to reference AWS::AccountId, i just used !GetAtt IamUser.Arn. It'd be awesome if the CloudFormation/AWS documentation were clearer about what the Ref function returns and what each of these attributes requires!

Answer (score 3):

The following will return **queue URL**, not ARN:

```
Resource: !Ref SQSQueue
```

But you need to use **queue ARN** in the policy:

```
Resource: !GetAtt SQSQueue.Arn
```